# Question on infinite products and normal convergence of series of function

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

So I have a question:

Let $U \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be an open set and let $f_{j} : U \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, $j \in  \mathbb{N}$ be a sequence of holomorphic functions. Prove or Disprove: if $\sum_{j = 0}^{\infty} |f_{j}|$ converges normally on $U$, then $\prod_{j = 1}^{\infty} (1 + f_{j}(z))$ converges normally on $U$.

So I think this is false. I tried considering a sequence of holomorphic functions on the unit disc. The only functions I know is $f_{j}(z) = z^{j}$. Am I on the right track? Please give not hints!

Thank you very much

Comment: It is true because on compact sets $|f_j|$ gets small as $j$ increases so $\Re(1+f_j) > 0$ eventually, so you can take $\log(1+f_j)$ which is about $f_j$ by the usual inequalities, hence the sum of the logarithms converges uniformly, hence the product does, while the zeros of the product are finite by the above ($|f_j|$ is eventually small, so you can have a few zeros for small $j$, but they are finite in number on any compact)

Answer (score 1):

$\prod (1+f_n(z))$ converges uniformly on some set iff $\sum |f_n(z)|$ converges uniformly on that set. This is a well known fact and you can find a proof in Rudin's RCA. Applying this to compact subsets of $U$ we get the result.